# problem with sudo apt-get update ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line

```
crazy@crazy:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for crazy: 
Hit:1 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Get:3 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [93.3 kB]   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB]  
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease                            
Hit:7 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                       
Get:8 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease [247 kB]
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release [1,347 B]
Get:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release.gpg [198 B]
Fetched 434 kB in 8s (52.2 kB/s)                                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F71 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release which is considered strong enough for security purposes
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
crazy@crazy:~$
```

how i can fix that ?

Comment: You need to remove google talkplugin from your repos.  I believe it's depreciated, and regardless, it's what's causing the issue.

Comment: ok  i did but nothing happened

Comment: Then it's somewhere else, that you didn't remove, or comment out.  apt isn't mysterious, it reads from its sources and then compiles a package list.  If apt-get update is still including talkplugin, it is present in one of the files.

Comment: i dont think because when i login to the websit he ask me to install the plugin first .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your /etc/apt/sources.list
This is the configuration file that determines where apt-get looks for packages. Below is the default 16.04 sources.list with comments removed.

﻿deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

Since you are getting "Failed to fetch" with something related to talkplugin, look for something in the configuration file related to talkplugin and remove it.